# How to do the sequential ordering?

Tags: c#

I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069238/how-can-i-distribute-x-items-as-evenly-as-possible-across-y-columns) Q/A , though it is working too some extent but not as expected. I want it to happen sequentially.How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) to combine the agents and accounts together (after repeating the list of agents to match or exceed the number of accounts). Then `GroupBy` agent.

```
var repeatCount = lstAccounts.Count / lstAgents.Count + 1;
var agents = Enumerable.Repeat(lstAgents, repeatCount).SelectMany(x => x);

// agents =      { "Agent1", "Agent2", "Agent3", "Agent1", "Agent2", "Agent3" }
// lstAccounts = { "1001"  , "1002"  , "1003"  , "1004"  , "1005" }

var result = agents
    .Zip(lstAccounts, (agent, account) => new { Agent = agent, Account = account })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Agent)
    .Select(g => new { Agent = g.Key, Accounts = g.Select(x => x.Account).ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

It might not be the fastest way to do it, but it's short and readable.

**Edit**

Another way (probably nicer) to achieve the same result is to start by mapping each account to an index of agent using `index % lstAgents.Count`.

```
var result = lstAccounts
    .Select((acc, index) => new { AgentIndex = index % lstAgents.Count, Account = acc })
    .GroupBy(x => x.AgentIndex)
    .Select(g => new { Agent = lstAgents[g.Key], Accounts = g.Select(x => x.Account).ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

The algorithm is very similar to the one proposed [by varocarbas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33946669/4588915), but expressed in a functional (not imperative) way.

Answer (score 1):

I think that conventional loops are the best approach here: easy-to-build, clear and very scalable-/modifiable-friendly. For example:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> results = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

int i = -1;
while (i < lstAccounts.Count - 1)
{   
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < lstAgents.Count; i2++)
    {
        i = i + 1;
        string curAccount = lstAccounts[i];
        string curAgent = lstAgents[i2];

        if (!results.ContainsKey(curAgent)) results.Add(curAgent, new List<string>());
        results[curAgent].Add(curAccount);

        if (i >= lstAccounts.Count - 1) break;
    }
}
```

Additionally, note that this approach is quite fast. As a reference: around 4-5 times faster (results after a simplistic test with one of the provided inputs and a `Stopwatch`) than the alternative proposed by Jakub in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach with linq extention. Split extension method will split the accounts list into "n" parts (number of agents) so that you can assign each part to agents.

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> lstAgents = new List<string>() { "Agent1", "Agent2","Agent3" };
        List<string> lstAccounts = new List<string>() { "1001", "1002" ,"1003", "1004", "1005" };

        var op = lstAccounts.Split(lstAgents.Count);

        int i = 0;

        foreach (var accounts in op)
        {
            //Get agent
            Console.WriteLine("Account(s) for Agent: ", lstAgents[i]);

            foreach (var acc in accounts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(acc);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            i++;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


 }

  static class LinqExtensions
  {
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int parts)
    {
        int i = 0;
        var splits = from item in list
                     group item by i++ % parts into part
                     select part.AsEnumerable();
        return splits;
    }
}
```